# decrypting CyproJS AES encrypted in Cryptodome python

Tags: python, angular, utf-8, cryptojs, pycryptodome

I am trying to decrypt (in angular) with cryptojs an encrypted python msg with cryptodome , so I have written this function in python to encrypt :

```
def encrypt_aes_256_cbc(data):

    key = os.getenv('ENCRYPT_KEY')
    iv = os.getenv('ENCRYPT_IV')
    
    # Ensure the key and IV are bytes
    key = bytes.fromhex(key)
    iv = bytes.fromhex(iv)

    # Convert data to bytes
    data_bytes = data.encode('utf-8')
    padded_data = _pkcs7_pad(data_bytes, algorithms.AES.block_size)
    # Create an AES-256 cipher object with CBC mode
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    # Encrypt the data
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)

    # Combine IV and ciphertext and encode in base64
    combined_data = iv + ciphertext
    encoded_ciphertext = base64.b64encode(combined_data).decode("utf-8")
    return encoded_ciphertext

def _pkcs7_pad(data, block_size):
    padder = padding.PKCS7(block_size).padder()
    padded_data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()
    print('padded data =', padded_data)
    return padded_data
```

and then i write in angular service a ts function to decrypt data :

```
export class EncryptDecryptService {
  iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(environment.iv);
  decryptKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(environment.keyDecryptage);


  decryptData(encrypted_json_string: string) {
    // const  or = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted_json_string).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      encrypted_json_string,
      this.decryptKey,
      { iv: this.iv }
    );
    console.log("decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1) =", decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

  }}
```

but i have this error : ERROR Error: Malformed UTF-8 data , what i have unterstood is when it will display data encryptedto utf8 it has seen mal caracter , but I can't resolve , if you have any idea , help , thank you

Comment: The Python function returns the concatenation of the IV and the ciphertext. But the JS function seems to be expecting that `encrypted_json_string` is only the ciphertext, without the IV.

Comment: A static IV is a vulnerability. Create a random IV for each encryption and concatenate this with the ciphertext (as the Python code already does). When decrypting (with the CryptoJS code), separate the two.

Comment: In addition, there is no need to implement the padding in the Python code yourself. PyCryptodome supports PKCS#7 padding with the [`Crypto.Util.Padding`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module) module.